Pandas adding last row of previous group
I have the following column B that I would like to use to get columns C and D (where B + C = D):
B       C        D

1       0        1
2       0        2
3       0        3
0       3        3
0       3        3
0       3        3
1       3        4
2       3        5
3       3        6
0       6        6
1       6        7

Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to go about this.
I've tried using various combinations of .groupby(), rolling apply, .ffill() and .cumsum() to no avail.
I've been able to split up B using
x = (df['B'].ne(0).diff() & df['B'].shift().ne())

but otherwise I'm pretty stumped.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Your question is not very clear. What is the exact logic you're trying to implement?

Edited for clarity - basically I'd like to group by B in such a way that C is the last row of each previous group in B

Assuming you really want the results, you can achieve your dataframe using this logic.  You can go straight from B to D using cumsum on a boolean series:
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,1]})
df['D'] = df['B'].ne(0).cumsum()
df['C'] = df['D'] - df['B']
df[['B', 'C', 'D']]

Output:
    B  C  D
0   1  0  1
1   2  0  2
2   3  0  3
3   0  3  3
4   0  3  3
5   0  3  3
6   1  3  4
7   2  3  5
8   3  3  6
9   0  6  6
10  1  6  7


Very nice and concise! If you don't want to reorder, you could initialize df['C'] = -df['B'] then update with df['C'] += df['D'] after computing D.

@argMaTea since the original question has a column A, if you want to consider A as group, modify this approach to use df['D'] = df['B'].ne(0).groupby(df['a']).cumsum()

I'm assuming you want to "group" the dataframe if B is 0 or not. I don't think there's nice vectorized solution to this, but you can try (if performance is problem, you can optimize it via numba):
out_C, out_D = [], []
flag, current_value = None, 0

for B in df["B"]:
    match [flag, fl := B > 0]:
        case [None, _]:
            flag = fl
        case [True, False] | [False, True]:
            current_value = out_D[-1]
            flag = fl

    out_C.append(current_value)
    out_D.append(B + current_value)

df["new_C"] = out_C
df["new_D"] = out_D

print(df)

Prints:
    B  C  D  new_C  new_D
0   1  0  1      0      1
1   2  0  2      0      2
2   3  0  3      0      3
3   0  3  3      3      3
4   0  3  3      3      3
5   0  3  3      3      3
6   1  3  4      3      4
7   2  3  5      3      5
8   3  3  6      3      6
9   0  6  6      6      6
10  1  6  7      6      7

